# CSS - Mozilla bug? box-shadow:inset not working properly

Tags: css, firefox, shadow

Basically the below code should simply be a white page with a shadow around the edge. This works fine in Chrome but I can't seem to get it to work in Firefox!

```
<html>
<head>
<style type=text/css>
body {
background:#ffffff;
font-family:arial;
margin:auto;
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 100px #333333;
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 100px #333333;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 100px #333333;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

View the page here:

http://pastehtml.com/view/bagevr6ke.html

Look at it in Chrome then Firefox, and tell me if you see a difference : )

Cheers

EDIT: So the post below explained how to fix the above code, a CSS reset worked and also i learned about quirk mode and doctypes  :)

However the CSS page i am working on is still suffering from this bug no matter what reset i use. I am not currently using a Doctype as i am not sure what i should put, or whether it would fix the bug.

Here is the complete site:

http://middle.dyndns-server.com/results.html

And the stylesheet:

```
body {
background:url('bg.png');
font-family:arial;
margin:auto;
box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 100px #333333;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 100px #333333;
-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 100px #333333;
}

#footer {
padding-bottom:10px;
margin-top:30px;
}

#page {
width:960px;
height:auto;

background-color:#ffffff;
#background:url('bg2.png');

/*Space*/
padding-top:0px;
padding-bottom:0px;
padding-left:0px;
padding-right:0px;
margin-top:-10px;
margin-bottom:0px;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;

/*Shadow*/
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 0px #999999,inset 0 0 10px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 0px #999999,inset 0 0 10px #000000;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 0px #999999,inset 0 0 10px #000000;

/*Border Radius*/
border-radius:0px 0px 20px 20px;
-moz-border-radius:0px 0px 20px 20px;
-webkit-border-radius:0px 0px 20px 20px;
-o-border-radius:0px 0px 20px 20px;

}

input[type=text] {
background: -webkit-gradient(linear,left top,right bottom,from(#333333),to(#666666));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #333333, #666666);
        filter: filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#333333', endColorstr='#666666'); 

border-width:1px;
border-style:solid;
border-color:#777777;
color:ffffff;
}

.line1 { 
float:left;
align:center; 
padding-bottom:0px;
}

hr { 
clear:left;
color:#111111;
}

/* The *normal* state styling */
.btn{
background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% bottom, 0% top,color-stop(0%, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)));
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#80333333', EndColorStr='#20000000');
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#80333333', EndColorStr='#20000000')";
    background-color:rgb(51, 51, 51);
    border:1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    padding:5px 10px;
box-shadow:0px 0px 6px rgb(130, 130, 130);
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 6px rgb(130, 130, 130);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 6px rgb(130, 130, 130);
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255);
    text-shadow:0px 0px 1px rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
/* The *hover* state styling */
.btn:hover{
    background-image:linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,color-stop(0%, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)));
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    box-shadow:0px 0px 6px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 6px rgb(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 6px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}

/* The *active* state styling */
.btn:active,.btn:focus{
    background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
    background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0% bottom, 0% top,color-stop(0%, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)));
    background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
}

a {
font-family:arial;
outline:none;
text-decoration:none;
color:333333;
}

a:link {
text-decoration:none;
}

a:visited {
text-decoration:none;
}

a:active {
text-decoration:none;
color:ffffff;
}

a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
}
```

I am sure its not all great but i am learning and this issue is my main focus right now : )

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Share the complete HTML of your page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%
}
```

http://jsbin.com/oyuzug

There is nothing in `body`, so it has no height.

The only reason it worked without this in Chrome is because you did not include a doctype as the very first line to enable Standards Mode.

**Test these in Chrome:**

Your original code: http://jsbin.com/urimah

Your original code with doctype: http://jsbin.com/urimah/2

Conclusion: Always include a doctype as the very first line to avoid [Quirks Mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) and the inconsistencies it brings between different browsers.

Comment: This does work for the example I have given but still doesn't fix my main issue (Its a lot more complex). I thought using a reset would be how it was solved xD

Thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome. I can't help you with your "main issue" unless you explain it.

Comment: I have updated the "OP", not sure what you call them on StackOverflow (Which I am liking a lot!). Thanks again!

Comment: One comment so far: `oncontextmenu="return false"` is the most annoying thing ever.

Comment: Ah yeah sorry about that, it was from another project and just got templated over...

Comment: The only reason it's not working in the link you provided is that you've not added the CSS I provided in this answer. However, looking at the page, I see that you need this: `html, body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }`, and you also need to remove `margin-top:-10px;` on `#page`.

Comment: Ah yes that does work! However the index still has the same issue, I can't think why this is?

Thanks again  :)

Comment: Not trying to be a troll here - but this answer has a major bug.  In the JSBin exmample, it works fine - but in practical use not so much.  I'm posting my answer as an explanation as to why this method is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox shows you the right thing because right now `body` has no `height`. So you have to define the `height` of your `body`.

Write this in your CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answer marked as correct [CSS - Mozilla bug? box-shadow:inset not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755682/css-mozilla-bug-box-shadowinset-not-working-properly#answer-7755767) does not work for me.  Why? Because the example includes no content.  When you style the `<body>` and `<html>` elements with `height: 100%` it creates a strange bug where the 100% is technically registering as **100% of the viewport rather than 100% of the window height**.

This is a great example of how to do this properly: http://www.dave-woods.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/full-height-updated.html.  Styling the `body` and `html` elements at `height: 100%` is correct, however, your inner-shadow needs to be attached to another element (can't be `body` or `html`) and then `min-height: 100%` as well as `box-shadow: 0 0 100px #000` attached to the shim, e.g.

```
html, body { height: 100% }
#styled-div { 
   min-height: 100%;
   box-shadow: 0 0 100px #000;
}
```