# Box-shadow on div with border-radius 50% visible on Mozilla and not Chrome / Edge

Tags: css, browser, sass, box-shadow

I have a little CSS issue and I have no idea why :

[image]

As you can see, Edge and Chrome are "normal" but on Mozilla the shadow is visible and I have no idea why...I checked on canaiuse (https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-boxshadow) and I didn't see compatibility problem, **someone have an idea why?**

Here is the html / css of this part :

HTML

My Doctype : `<!DOCTYPE html>`

```
<div class="myclass col-5">
    <a href="#" data-balloon="..." data-balloon-pos="down" class="btn bg-color-yellow"><i class="fas fa-camera-retro" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#" data-balloon="..." data-balloon-pos="down" class="btn bg-color-yellow-light"><i class="fas fa-images" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    <a href="#" data-balloon="..." data-balloon-pos="down" class="btn bg-color-grey"><i class="fas fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</div>
```

CSS - SASS (here is my .scss before I compile)

```
.myclass {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding-right: 0;

    @include position(absolute, 0, 0, null, null);

    a.btn {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 0;
        position: relative;
        transition: all .2s ease-out;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 $grey-dark;
        z-index: 50;

        &:hover {
          transform: translate(2px, -2px);
          box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px $grey-dark;
        }

        .fa-cogs,
        .fa-camera-retro,
        .fa-images {
          color: $white;
        }
        svg {
          display: block;
          margin: 0 auto;
          @include vertical-align();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to remove the `data-balloon` part of my link just to see if the `balloon.css` I the problem but nothing change

PS : if you need the CSS after I compile tell me, but you should see what I do with the code bellow

**EDIT** : Here is a snippet where you can see the problem if you open it on **MOZILLA**

```css
div {
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 0;
}

div a {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 black;
  z-index: 50;
  background: orange;
}

div a:hover {
  transform: translate(2px, -2px);
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px black;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
    <a></a>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the doctype of your html page ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7755682/css-mozilla-bug-box-shadowinset-not-working-properly#answer-7755767

Comment: It's not an "isset" problem @X-Blaster, but I will check thanks

Comment: I edit my question and add the Doctype @X-Blaster

Comment: Maybe you should remove `box-shadow` property from `a.btn` at all if it has only zero values anyway and add it only for `:hover` event?

Comment: @Heidel it works, but I still find it strange that Mozilla show some shadow when other browser don't...with `0 0 0 0 mycolor` it should'nt be visible :/

Comment: @Mickael Leger It seems there is some common problem with FF https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24721822/firefox-not-rendering-correctly-with-border-radius-box-shadow-and-border

Comment: @Heidel yeah I saw it too but it was on "inset" shadow, here it's just normal shadow ! Maybe the problem is `border-radius : 50%` i don't know :/ I correct my problem with by removing it or addinf `transparent` but still confusing, I knew Edge do strange thing but if Mozilla start too...!

Comment: @Mickael Leger if it's a FF bug, there is nothing you can do with it.

Comment: @Heidel, ok, I will change my CSS as suggested but hope they fix it in the future it's strange behavior

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code and its working fine. I don't see any `box-shadow` issue here...However if issue is there you can just set box-shadow color to `transparent` at normal state and change it on `:hover`

```css
div {
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .2s ease-out;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 transparent;
  z-index: 50;
  background: orange;
}

div:hover {
  transform: translate(2px, -2px);
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 0px 0px grey;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Sure it works, I can remove the box-shadow too as suggested in the comment but I'd like to understand why? I ask my collegue to check it too and it's the same, it works on Edge / Chrome but Mozilla show some shadow

Comment: I add your snippet in my question with `black` instead of `transparet` and `grey`, if you open it with Mozilla you should see the problem, no?

Comment: I am using mozilla `59.0.1 (64 bits)` on `Microsoft Windows 10 Professionnel`, maybe a Window problem. I will change my CSS to avoid it but still strange, thanks for looking and anwsering my question

Comment: I just tried and still the same, as said in comment I think it's just a mozilla bug, maybe only on window if in mac you can't see it